# NAND flash page layout

Tags: flash

I'm a beginner. I was going through the [`Nand flash memory layout`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_fs_cfgspare.htm). It is given that, page layout can be,

1. `Data area` & `Spare area` alternatively.
2. Data area in the beginning & spare area at the end.

I'd like to know why the latter is preferred in most cases. Because, I referred DM37x, OMAP 35x and many others, which follow the second layout. Thanks in advance.

Please direct me if I'm in the wrong part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: I wouldn't put much store in what TI do, they're a nightmare. I **would**, however, do what TI do if you're hoping to develop on TI hardware - it's just easier that way.